# How I can get the results from many to many relation in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have N:M relationship on tables Car and Accident, I establish that but I could not return the result in view "Adminclaims" page
here is my code:
Accident Model

```
 class Accident extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'accidents';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ReportNumber';
    protected $fillable = [
        'ReportNumber',
        'Location',
        'Date',
    ];

   public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class,'accident_participateds','reportNo','vehicleId');
        

}
```

Car Model

```
class Car extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'cars';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'customer_id',
        'color',
        'model_no',
        'company',
    ];


    public function accidents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Accident::class,'accident_participateds','vehicleId','reportNo')->withPivot(['damageAmount', 'IBAN']);
    }
}
```

Pivot Table

```
class accidentParticipated extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = ['reportNo','vehicleId'];
    protected $table = 'accident_participateds';


    protected $fillable = [
        'reportNo',
        'vehicleId',
        'damageAmount',
        'IBAN',
    ];


}
```

Controller

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function AdminClaims()
    {
        
        $car = Car::with('accidents')->get();
        $accident = Accident::with('car')->get();
        return view('admin.AdminClaims',compact('car','accident'));
    }
}
```

And the last view

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Report Number</th>
                            <th>Vehicle Id</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Damage Amount</th>
                            <th>IBAN</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    
                    @foreach((array) $car as $car)
                        @foreach($car->$accident as $Acciden)   
                                    {<tr>
                                    <td>{{$Acciden->pivot->ReportNumber}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$Acciden->pivot->vehicleId}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$Acciden->pivot->Location}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$Acciden->pivot->Date}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$Acciden->pivot->damageAmount}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$Acciden->pivot->IBAN}}</td>
                                     </tr>
                        @endforeach
                           
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
   
       </div>
```

I don't know where is the error
ErrorException

```
Attempt to read property "[{"ReportNumber":123,"Location":"rood","Date":"2022-05-28","car":[{"id":9999999999,"customer_id":1233455432,"color":"red","model_no":2020,"company":"j class","pivot":
```

Comment: I don't have experience with using a model for the pivot table, but [reading the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) suggests you're doing a few things wrong.  1) It looks like you should use the `->using()` method on the `Accident` and `Car` models; 2) The pivot model class should extend the `Pivot` class, not `Model`.  OTOH do you really need the model for the pivot? You don't need it to access pivot attributes.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. Actually, I need to apply Many to Many and print the results Only. Not mandatory to use pivot

Comment: I think the problem in the last file (printing results) as it shows ErrorException

Attempt to read property "name" on null

Comment: "*Attempt to read property "name" on null*"? Your question does not show that error?